# Put ZIP file on server for public

Tags: security, domain, file-sharing

I was wondering if I can upload a ZIP file to my server and then make it public by sharing the link with others

For example I was thinking about an URL like this:

http://mydomain.com/files/test.zip

The question I have if this method of sharing files is secure.

Answer (score 4):

It's obviously possible to do this, and it's no more (or less) risky than putting up any other content on your server and make it public.

Comment: Hopefully needless to say, but if you have directory listing enabled on your web-server then the file will show up on Google and friends.